# converting csv to xlsx numbers stored as text issue in mixed type data

Tags: python, csv, xlsxwriter

I have a large dataset, which consists of both floats, ints, and strings in cells.
My original data set is csv format. when converting to xlsx, I get numbers stored as text error.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901884/conversion-text-to-number-in-python) which gives script if you are manually writing to cells.

as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx) which shows how to convert csv to text.

This is my splicing of the two scripts:

```
import csv
import os
import glob
import xlsxwriter

from xlsxwriter import Workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx', {'strings_to_numbers': True})

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)

workbook.close()
```

Which doesn't work for resolving the numbers stored as text issue. That issue persists.

I want to write numbers as numbers as it is converting the csv to xlsx

Comment: Can you also post some sample data that is giving you an issue? That way we can recreate with your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your `for` loop is overriding the workbook variable that you have defined using the "strings_to_numbers". Try removing that line since it looks like you want to add worksheets to a single workbook, correct?

Based on the examples you linked, it looks like this is just a small copy/paste error :).